# Segfault -- but the pointer isn't NULL

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I am doing something like the following in C:

```
void *initialize()
{
    my_type *ret = malloc(sizeof(my_type));
    return (void*)ret;
}

void test()
{
    my_type* ret = (mytype*)initialize();
    my_type x = *ret;
}
```

It crashes on the dereference with:

```
Received signal 11 (Segmentation fault: 11)
```

The pointer is not null: I tried printing the pointer, and got a value.

I also tried making a new my_type right in the test function, like this:

```
my_type* new = malloc(sizeof(my_type));
```

When I print the integer representations of new and ret, they are integers very close to each other. So these things should be nearby in memory.

Comment: `printf` needs a format specifier what is the type of `mytype->field`?

Comment: What is the value of `mytype->field`?

Comment: what's the type of `field`

Comment: You're using `mytype->field` as a format string, which is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: Segmentation fault isn't just for null pointers, it's for any pointer to an address that isn't assigned to the process.

Comment: field is an int. I did printf("%d", mytype->field) and it still didn't work

Comment: Share the `mytype` struct definition

Comment: The first argument to `printf()` must be `char*`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `printf("%d", ret->field);`?

Comment: OK, I made a mistake with the printf(). But it still doesn't work: I'll edit the code to show you something which doesn't work

Comment: Did you try to remove the (unecessary) casting like so: `my_type * ret = initialize();` and compiled this with all warnings on (`-Wall` for GCC)?

Comment: malloc(sizeof(mytype)); what is mytype here variable if so how is it defined ?, this could be an error incase it is defined as pointer

Comment: There is a compiler warning if that's relevant: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size.

Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: What is `mytype->...`? Is this a typo?

Comment: @alk If I remove the cast, it gives me a new warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast. And still the segfault.

Comment: In the line you are calling `initialze()`? If yes you most propably are missing the prototype for `void * initialise(void)`.

Comment: its `ret->field` and not `mytype->field`

Comment: @alk Bingo! Add that as an answer! I was missing the function prototype!

Comment: Another good example why one shall always fix the code until no more warnings are issued by the compiler and why casting it evil (or ar least unnecessary) in nearly every case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the compiler does not know a function it assumes `int` as its return type.

If the size of `int` is different to what the function actually returns the code generated by the compiler might miss to return the correct number of bytes.

However, the code you posted is correct and will perform as expected, as `initialise()` occurs before where it is used, so the compiler then already knows which type the function returns.

Most propably the original code (you did **not** post) looks something like this (without the prototype for `initialise()`):

Try the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* To pull in malloc's protoype. */

void * initialize(void);

void test()
{
    my_type x, * ret = initialize();
    if (ret)
      x = *ret;
}

void * initialize(void)
{
    my_type * ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret));
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Odds are that `field` is either (a) a char array, (b) a pointer to char, or (c) an integer value. yes?

In all three cases, the printf() statement is expecting `field` to be a pointer to a null terminated character string. At least in the example code you provide, it is not initialized to anything.

So... the SIGSEGV is because (a) `field` is an uninialized char array and who knows how far out into memory the printf() is reading looking for a null terminator, (b) field is an uninitialized pointer... just because it is not zero, does not mean it is a valid memory address, or (c) you're trying to pass an integer or some other value to printf() as a pointer to char, which it is not.

Any one of those three will produce the result you report.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you have 2 types with name are close

`mytype`  and `my_type`

```
my_type *ret = malloc(sizeof(mytype));
```

and

```
my_type* ret = (mytype*)initialize();
```

may be it's a typo that you use 2 differents name for the same type. and this could cause crash

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, `field` is an `int` so

the

```
printf(mytype->field);
```

should be

```
printf("%d\n", ret->field);
```

From [printf()](http://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) page in the cplusplus site

> int printf ( const char * format, ... );
>
> Print formatted data to stdout
>
> Writes the C string pointed by format to the standard output (stdout). If format includes format specifiers (subsequences beginning with %), the additional arguments following format are formatted and inserted in the resulting string replacing their respective specifiers.